# In python Dataframes, How to add multiple rows related to single row in other dataframe as additional columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

First Data set : These players playing in a tournament. These dataset 
records players and there teams.

```
df_team = pd.DataFrame({
'Country': ["India","India","India","AUS","AUS","AUS"],
'Player': ["SACHIN","RAHUL","SAURBH","STEVE","SHEN","RICKY"]
})
```

second data set: These record set have runns scored by batsman in first and second innings in the matched they played. Note some players and not played some matches.

```
df_scores = pd.DataFrame({
    'Player': ["SACHIN", "SACHIN", "RAHUL", "RAHUL", "SAURBH", "STEVE", "RICKY", "RICKY", "RICKY", "RICKY"],
    'INNG1': [70, 10, 55, 75, 100, 7, 75, 55, 45, 17],
    'INNG2': [50, 20, 35, 25, 100, 17, 25, 45, 65, 71]
})
```

result dataset needed: Here we want to have a row per team. All batsmans score will be recorded in single row. We need this to feed to NN and hence position is also important.

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': ["India", "India", "India", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS"],
    'Player': ["SACHIN", "RAHUL", "SAURBH", "STEVE", "SHEN", "RICKY"],
    '1-INNG1': [70, 55, 100, 7, 'NA', 75],
    '1-INNG2': [50, 55, 100, 7, 'NA', 25],
    '2-INNG1': [10, 75, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 55],
    '2-INNG2': [20, 75, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 45],
    '3-INNG1': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 45],
    '3-INNG2': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 65],
    '4-INNG1': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 17],
    '4-INNG2': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 71],
})
```

How to obtain this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
g = df_scores.groupby('Player').cumcount().add(1)
df = df_scores.set_index(['Player',g]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = ['{}-{}'.format(j, i) for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
        1-INNG1  1-INNG2  2-INNG1  2-INNG2  3-INNG1  3-INNG2  4-INNG1  4-INNG2
Player                                                                        
RAHUL      55.0     35.0     75.0     25.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
RICKY      75.0     25.0     55.0     45.0     45.0     65.0     17.0     71.0
SACHIN     70.0     50.0     10.0     20.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
SAURBH    100.0    100.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
STEVE       7.0     17.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

df_result = df_team.join(df, on='Player')
print (df_result)
  Country  Player  1-INNG1  1-INNG2  2-INNG1  2-INNG2  3-INNG1  3-INNG2  \
0   India  SACHIN     70.0     50.0     10.0     20.0      NaN      NaN   
1   India   RAHUL     55.0     35.0     75.0     25.0      NaN      NaN   
2   India  SAURBH    100.0    100.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
3     AUS   STEVE      7.0     17.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
4     AUS    SHEN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
5     AUS   RICKY     75.0     25.0     55.0     45.0     45.0     65.0   

   4-INNG1  4-INNG2  
0      NaN      NaN  
1      NaN      NaN  
2      NaN      NaN  
3      NaN      NaN  
4      NaN      NaN  
5     17.0     71.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. First count unique values per groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
2. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and change order of first level by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
3. Flatten `MultiIndex` by list comprehension
4. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`